# how to select an option from an autocomplete field in selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

i am testing a form of post a feed. where user can notify some existing user.
while i am enter any data or character in the field its id is changes.

eg. if at the initial stage verifyValue id=token-input-auto_complete
enter a data in the field ani
verifyValue id=token-input-auto_complete ani

after enter the data in the field it shows only the character in the field but not shows any dropdown options

Comment: Would love to see the page, or the underlying html you are trying to test.
Likely you need to trigger a javascript event to get the autocomplete to trigger. than you can use a WaitFor for the dropdown elements to appear and then select the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a jQuery autocomplete? Or some other type of autocomplete (please name it if so)

This is how I select a jQuery autocomplete list value in selenium: (note this is typed in code, not recorded code). It is a bit tricky, you have to make it trigger the autocomplete, then you have to highlight the value, then you have to select it.

```
string locator = "id=token-input-auto_complete";
string value = "CATS";
selenium.Focus(locator);
selenium.Type(locator, value);
selenium.KeyDown(locator, "\\40");
Thread.Sleep(50);
selenium.KeyDown(locator, "\\40");
Thread.Sleep(50);
selenium.KeyDown(locator, "\\13");
Thread.Sleep(50);
```

Comment: @user1421851 please select this as the answer if it helped you solve the issue.

Comment: The Post was looking for an IDE solution, not webdriver.

Comment: Sleeps should be avoided whenever possible and replaced with WaitFor's.