# Listen click event with Selenium2 and Behat do not work if opened browser has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I am testing my UI with Behat and Selenium2. This is my scenariuo:

```
Scenario: Invite a Facebook friend
  Given database is empty
  Then I go to "/somewhere"
  Given I follow "Invite a friend"
  And I fill in "friends" with "Acme"
  Then I wait for the suggestion box to appear
  Then I select first suggestion
  Then show last response
```

I have autocomplete (jquery-ui) box. All sentences works as I expect and are green, but user is not redirecte

```
/**
 * @Then /^I wait for the suggestion box to appear$/
 */
public function iWaitForTheSuggestionBoxToAppear()
{
    $this->getSession()->wait(
        1000,
        "$('.ui-autocomplete').children().length > 0"
    );
}
```

But I've added a second sentence

```
/**
 * @Then /^I select first suggestion$/
 */
public function iSelectFirstSuggestion()
{
    $this->getSession()->executeScript(
        "$('.ui-autocomplete').children().children().click()"
    );
}
```

Selenium console told me:

```
10:06:01.426 INFO - ... $('.ui-autocomplete').children().length > 0;, ...
10:06:01.439 INFO - ...
10:06:01.545 INFO - ... $('.ui-autocomplete').children().length > 0;...
10:06:01.559 INFO - ...
10:06:01.669 INFO - ... $('.ui-autocomplete').children().children().click(); ...
```

After a click users should be redirected to /invite/ url.

```
    $("#friends").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            document.location.href = '/invite/' + ui.item.uid;
            return false;
        }
    })
```

Contrariwise, this script does not always work. When selenium open the browser, if I open another window, test returns all steps as green. If not: If I continue to watch opened window and this maintain the focus, ... click and redirection, they do not do their job.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

After a day of trying I came to the conclusion that selenium with firefox (as well as phantomjs with WebDriver in my case) do not capture all the required events from jquery autocomplete to work properly because the data entry is not fully emulates the use of manual.

At the end of the day the bottom line is that just calling via javascript $('element'). autocomplete('search') I am sure that the ui-autocomplete items are showed

Today I've read and tried everything about it:)

Similar things:

- [with javascript cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441815/javascript-cucumber-tests-pass-using-selenium-driver-but-fail-when-using-polter)
- [with capybara2](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-do-jqueryui-autocomplete-with-capybara-2/)
- [with selenium ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095234/how-to-select-an-option-from-an-autocomplete-field-in-selenium-ide)
- [with junit](http://blog.buberel.org/2010/07/howto-test-jquery-ajax-autocomplete-menus-with-selenium.html)